# Bing search api not the same data as the web search

Tags: c#, bing, bing-api, bing-search

I am using the Bing search to look for some items and using the Bing Search API version I get the same results.

However on the web search there is under the link to the site a grey "Fact Row" or as the class is named "b_factrow" this row has some data that I want to try and read out.

On the API search I get all the other data from the search but not this fact row and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Yes I could screen scrap but doing this is never easy and let be honest if Bing change the layout/names etc etc then the app I am building will break until I amend it which is not ideal.

Anyway if anyone knows how to gather this Fact Row data that would be great.